# What is the duration of Stress Testing in Apache JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I had tried doing stress testing in jmeter but could not get the timing in which it should be finished

Answer (score 0):

Duration can be controlled by checking Scheduler in Thread Group and setting a duration.

Ensure you also check infinite iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Set time in scheduler in thread group itself to  run all of the request under thread group for a specific time. For example : set number of threads as 10 and ramp up as 2 and scheduler as 1800 (milliseconds) and enable the forever option. All the requests under threadgroup will run for 30 mins. And jmeter will send  each request under thread group 10 times in 2 seconds. This will go on for 30 mins.

Note: if you want to run only a specific request. Put that request under a loop controller and set forever option enabled in loop controller.here you disable the forever option in thread group setting.

If I understood your question correctly, there is no specific time to do stress test. Its all about the type of request you send. If its light weighy it can run longer. Or if its heavy,then server will be down in a few minutes. Its all based on the server bandwidth and server,Lb config that you have to find. Find the bottleneck and then proceed discovering things.